# How to document feature-gated derived traits?

Tags: rust, attributes, conditional-compilation, rustdoc, cargo-features

I understand that I can use the [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute) attribute to conditionally derive Trait implementations for types. For example, A struct `MyStruct` which always implements `Clone`, `Copy`, and `Debug`, but which implements `PartialEq` if and only if the `my-feature` feature is enabled, can be defined as follows:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "my-feature", derive(PartialEq)]
struct MyStruct;
```

But is it possible to make the generated documentation reflect this? I would like the `rustdoc`-generated documentation to state that `PartialEq` is implemented for `MyStruct` *if and only if* the `my-feature` feature is enabled.

So far, I have only accomplished two outcomes, neither of which I want:

1. If I compile the docs with the `my-feature` feature enabled, the generated documentation just says that `MyStruct` implements `PartialEq`, with no mention of feature gating
2. If I compile the docs without the `my-feautre` feature enabled, generated documentation does not indicate that `PartialEq` is or can be implemented for `MyStruct`.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible. You'd need to add `#[doc(cfg(feature = "my-feature"))]` ([which is not yet stable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43781)) to the *implementation*, but there's no way to provide that when using `#[derive(...)]` as far as I know.